# How can you make a php variable be with unique MySQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make sure each $number_of_audits is unique to it's row?  It only shows the value of the last row repeated over and over again.  I thought I set up the $temp_row to do this but something  is wrong.  I know this isn't PDO, but it will be later.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($row[site_id] > 0){
                $qry = "SELECT count(audit_instanceID) AS AID
                    FROM audit_instance
                    WHERE auditID = {$row['auditID']}
                    AND trash IS NULL and site_id='$_SESSION[siteID]' and corporate_auditID = '0'";
            }
            else {
                $qry = "SELECT count(audit_instanceID) AS AID
                    FROM audit_instance
                    WHERE auditID = {$row['auditID']}
                    AND trash IS NULL and corporate_auditID = '0'";
            }
            $temp_result = qry($qry);
            $temp_row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp_result);
                $number_of_audits = $temp_row['AID'];
                if ($number_of_audits > 0) {
                    $view_audit_button="<a class='btn btn-default btn-xs' role='button'    href='answer_audit.php?auditID=$row[auditID]&action=view_audits' value='View Audits: $number_of_audits' \">View Audits: $number_of_audits</a>";
                } else {
                    $view_audit_button="";
                }
```

I also tried:

```
foreach ($temp_row as $number_of_audits)
            {
                $number_of_audits = $temp_row['AID'];
            }
                if ($number_of_audits > 0) {
                    $view_audit_button="<a class='btn btn-default btn-xs' role='button'    href='answer_audit.php?auditID=$row[auditID]&action=view_audits' value='View Audits: $number_of_audits' \">View Audits: $number_of_audits</a>";
                } else {
                    $view_audit_button="";
                }
```

Comment: re-write as a single `join`ed query, e.g. `SELECT id, count(id) FROM ... JOIN ... GROUP BY ...`, then you get your id and count together at the same time.

Comment: `$temp_row = mysql_fetch_array($temp_result);` suddenly a `mysql_*` function appears!

Comment: `mysql_` doesnt work with `mysqli`. Mysqli supports parameterized queries, you dont need PDO, use parameterized queries here. Open to SQL injections as is.

Comment: because you haven't make a loop. With your method you always going to get the last record

Comment: It would be the foreach loop?  I did see that now, the mysql instead of mysqli

Comment: Where would I implement the foreach loop?  It just am trying the SELECT audit_instanceID, count(audit_instanceID) AS AID
                        FROM ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you want to join a table, and I would change the query like Marc B's comment suggests. I assume you have some query that already provides the auditID. Something like

```
SELECT [...], site_id, auditID, [...] 
FROM sometable [...]
```

The quick solution would be a sub-query (although some find them dirty and/or ugly):

```
SELECT [...], site_id, auditID,
  (SELECT COUNT(ai.audit_instanceID) FROM audit_instance ai
   WHERE ai.auditID = auditID 
     AND ai.trash IS NULL 
     AND ai.site_id=site_id
     AND ai.corporate_auditID = '0'
  ) as AID, [...] 
FROM sometable [...]
```

Afterwards your `$row` already has the wanted `AID` entry, with the count of audit instances.

I guess there could be a problem, if `site_id` can be `NULL`. You then would have to check (change) the `site_id` line to

```
     AND (site_id IS NULL OR ai.site_id=site_id)
```

to perfectly reflect what your code said before. If in those cases both have to be `NULL` the query gets more complicated, but I guess you'll figure it out.